# .flat is not a function only with jest

Tags: jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest, babel-polyfill, core-js

When running my tests with jest, I had the above error;

```
Error: Uncaught [TypeError: array.map(...).flat is not a function]
```

Following the solution from that issue, https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/828

I've installed `core-js` on dependencies and putting this in `jest.config.js`

```
setupFiles: ['core-js'],
```

I'd receive that another error;

```
Error: Uncaught [Error: Not supported]
```

And this is occurring only with jest, I'm using babel and webpack on my application and storybook without errors on `flat`.

My `jest.config.js`

```
const PATH = require('./path')

module.exports = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./rtl.setup.js'],
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js'],
  verbose: true,
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '@components(.*)$': `${PATH.source}/components/$1`
  },
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

per https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/828#issuecomment-433976880

this problem can be solved by running

```
npm install --save-dev core-js
```

and adding `core-js` to your jest config's setupFiles

```
"setupFiles": ["core-js"]
```

Comment: For my create-react-app project I was able to fix this by adding `import 'core-js/stable';` to the top of my `setupTests.ts` file.

Comment: Did you need to install the dependency or did it work within CRA

Answer (score 5):

I installed `core-js` (`@3.4.1`) and it worked for me.
Also had to add `import 'core-js';` at the top of my test file's imports.

Edit: Using it in a `create-react-app` project that is not ejected, so I don't access `webpack` files and I don't have a custom config for `jest` (nor `jest-ts`).

Answer (score 4):

This error happens if your node version is old. Try to update it to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Searching more about core-js, since it's substituting @babel/polyfill, that config has worked to me.

```
[
  "@babel/preset-env",
  {
    "targets": {
      "node": 4
    },
    "useBuiltIns": "usage",
    "corejs": 3
  }
]
```

And core-js@3 being installed as a dependency.